# RLE алгоримт сжатия, добавить проверку если больше 9 одинаковых символов начинать подсчет заново

Tags: java, update, rle

Подскажите, как улучшить существующий код:

```
public class RLE {
    public static String encode(String s) {
        if (s == "" || s == null) return "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int count = 1;
        char previous = s.charAt(0);
        char current;

        for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
            current = s.charAt(i);
            if (current == previous) {
                count++;
            } else {
                if (count == 1) {
                    sb.append(previous);
                } else if (count > 1) {
                    sb.append(count).append(previous);
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
            previous = current;

        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Сейчас результат сжатия 'Heeeeeeeeeeeellooooo' -> H12e2l

Ожидаемый результат с условием: количество букв в повторе больше девяти, должно быть две комбинации буква цифра
'Heeeeeeeeeeeellooooo' -> H9e3e2l5o

Comment: вместо `if (s == "" || s == null) return "";` `if (s == null || "".equals(s)) return "";`

Comment: Мож, просто `if (current == previous)` дополнить до `if ((current == previous) && (count < 9))`?

Comment: не понимаю, почему в строке H9e3e2l5o подряд 2 сокращения с символом 'e'?

Answer (score 0):

у тебя не проходит "последний" цикл: когда "предыдущий" элемент есть, а текущего нет
можешь или изменить цикл чтобы он проходил на 1 больше итераций
или добавить код после цикла (придется часть кода дублировать)

Comment: если хочешь максимум 9 сокращение, добавь внутрь `if (current == previous)` проверку `if (count>8) ...` обрабатывающий такой случай